# Angular - ng-class or class

Tags: angular, class, ng-class

i would like to know, whats the real benefit of using ngClass/[ngClass] instead of class in Angular? Are there any performance differences?

```
<div class="foobar">text</div>
```

or

```
<div ngClass="foobar">text</div>
```

Comment: you can add class based on a condition using [ngClass]

Comment: That's because you don't take advantage of the @Input notation with `[ngClass]="var"`. In your case, there is indeed no benefit.

Comment: This is incorrectly marked as a duplicate. The linked question is asking about `[class.foobar]`, this question is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*If you want to add `class`, use `class` as below.

```
class="className"
```

*If you want to add one `class` conditionally, you can use `class/ngClass in angular` as below.

```
[class.className]="condition"  
[ngClass]="{'className': condition}"
```

*If you want to add more than one `class` conditionally, you have two way.

`Way 1:` Use `class in angular` as below:

```
[class.className1]="condition1"  
[class.className2]="condition2"
.
.
.
```

`Way 2:` Use `ngClass in angular` as below:

```
[ngClass]="{'class1': condition1 , 'class2': condition2 ... }"
```

And clearly the 2nd way is better than the 1st. Phew !!